# C - Read text/sentences from file into an array of strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, file, scanf

I am a beginner programmer , studying in an uni. at the moment.
My homework: write a text-based adventere game (after less than 2 months of programming studies :/ ).

The teacher said that the text which the game is using, should be stored in a file.
At the beginning, the program should read in "all the text" from that file, and then, the program should use the text from strings (I guess).

My first thought was that I will read in 1 sentence into 1 string but that just does not want to work out, because the sentences have spaces between the words ofcourse, but when I try to read it in, when the program sees a space, it stores the word in another string instead of the same one.

So, because of this, for example:
I have 4 lines in my txt file:
Line 1: Which way should you go?
Line 2: Forward
Line 3: Left
Line 4: Right

I thought that when I read the text in to 4 strings, then LINE 1 will be in the first string, LINE 2 in the second , etc.
But what happened? 'Which' was in the first string, "way" was in the second string, etc.

Sorry for the bad explanation, but I hope you guys understand what my problem is.
How can I read the Line 1 into the first string ONLY?
I thought the program will not count space as "okay, I should put the word after this space into a new string" ..

This is my code which is causing this "error":

```
char decisions[4][200];
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("text.txt", "r");
fscanf(fp, "%s %s %s %s", &decisions[0], &decisions[1], &decisions[2], &decisions[3]);
fclose(fp);

printf("%s\n %s\n %s\n %s\n", decisions[0], decisions[1], decisions[2], decisions[3]);
```

decisions[0] should have the question read in from the first line of my txt file, and the other 3 should have the 3 chosing options. Thats what I would like to happen :/

Comment: Look at `fgets()`.

Comment: I will look into it, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read line by line, you may use `fgets`. If you know that MAX bytes of each string is 200 and you have 4 lines, pass it to `fgets` into this loop:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    fgets(decisions[i], 200, fp);
  }
```

`fgets` read n bytes into buffer until found new line or EOF. So, be sure that each line will have no more than 200 chars each.

Comment: Ohh , what an awesome answer!
You actually wrote it for my code.
Thanks man, this helps a lot actually, now I start to understand the use of fgets :)
This is a definitive upvote from me! :) 
Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Although you shouldn't, you *can* do it with `fscanf`.

Content of `text.txt`

```
"Whussup?" "All of the things that have not been screwn tightly to the ground" "Buh, who cares!" "You don't wanna know, mate!"
"Why?" "Because!" "Ask Joe!" "I'm a doctor, not an engineer!"
```

The first line can be parsed with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
// ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!
int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char decisions[4][200];

  fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");
  fscanf(fp, "\"%199[^\"]\" \"%199[^\"]\" \"%199[^\"]\" \"%199[^\"]\"",
         decisions[0], decisions[1], decisions[2], decisions[3]);
  fclose(fp);
  printf("LINE1: %s\nLINE2: %s\nLINE3: %s\nLINE4: %s\n", decisions[0],
         decisions[1], decisions[2], decisions[3]);
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The trick is the `\"%199[^\"]\"`, it takes up to 199 characters that are not a `"` and are between double quotes followed by a space. But the format of `text.txt` must be strict or it doesn't work!

But really, try to use `fgets` or similar, reduces the amount of headaches by a large amount!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I am really pleased that you wrote this just for my code!
Although, I think I will take my time to understand fgets, as that looks much easier to do with larger amount of text.

Although I appreciate this answer, and I push an upvote for it!
Thank you! :)

Answer (score -2):

Explicitly use newlines as separators in format string

```
fscanf(fp, "%s[\n]%s[\n]%s[\n]%s", &decisions[0], &decisions[1], &decisions[2], &decisions[3]);
```

Comment: Have you actually tried your suggested solution? Don't think it will work. From the `fscanf` manual about the `%s`: "Matches  a  sequence  of  **non-white-space**  characters". The first line of OP's input has white spaces.

Comment: I wonder what it is about stack overflow that causes an inability to separate the conversion specifiers `%s` and `%[]`. Most curious.